# Should I change the Envelope From for Sendmail

Tags: apache-2.2, sendmail, email-bounces, email

Currently the Envelope from is `apache_user@mydomain.com`.
All emails sent from this website use the From address of `contact@mydomain.com`.

Should I change the Envelope send address to match the From address?  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to an email address which is read by someone, preferably by sysadmin/postmaster. This is because the bounces will be sent back to that address.
Usually apache_user@domain.com doesn't even exists.
Can match the From address.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it reduces a little chances of being hit by anti-spam filters.